# How do I define how much windows open In Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

For example I have amount = input()

I have tried driver.get(), amount but I just opens a blank chrome tab.
How would i go about telling it how much times it opens?

Comment: Your question is too unclear

Comment: I think he just wants tabs open depending on the amount of input.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(int(amount)):
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
```

If you would like "amount" of tabs just do this.